# Animated hiding of status bar by changing alpha

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm hiding the navigation bar using this code:

```
if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.65,
                    delay: 0.0,
                    options: .CurveEaseInOut | .AllowUserInteraction,
                    animations: {
                        navBar.alpha = 0.0
                    },
                    completion: { finished in
                })
            }
```

How can I also hide the status bar in the same animation using `alpha` or some other means that actually doesn't make the content shift?

I know I can do this to hide the status bar, but it causes the view to shift:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)
```

Basically upon scrolling my `UIWebView`, I'm hiding the navigation bar and I want to do the same with status bar, but in a way that allows you to continue scrolling.

Comment: You can't. The problem is that the status bar doesn't belong to you; it's a window imposed by the system on top of your app. - The shifting is because you've constrained your interface with respect to the top layout guide, which moves when the status bar appears or disappears.

Comment: Any idea on how to allow the UIWebView to continue scrolling during the hiding of the status bar?

Comment: I'm afraid my rather dumb solution would be just to hide the status bar for this view controller, from the get-go.